# Adding methods to object properties of a mongoose schema

Tags: mongoose

Is it possible to add methods to the *properties* of the mongoose schema?

So you could access it like this

```
user.properties[2].toString()
```

**schema**

```
var User = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    properties: [{
        name: String,
        other: String,
        ...
    }],
    ...
});
```

Is it possible to add a method to all of its "`properties`"?

```
User.properties.methods.toString = function() {
    return (this.name + this.other);
    // `this` would be [property]
}
```

Comment: I doubt that it's possible. But, perhaps, you'll be satisfied with something like [Mongoose Getters and Setters feature](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/getters-setters.html).

Comment: If you'll tell us more about your actual problem, we may be able to recommend you an alternative solution.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny Thanks! Just wanted to know whether it was possible.